# Accordion problems ie6- 9

Tags: javascript, html

I have an accordion on my page which works in FF, Chrome, Safari and IE10 but the accordion does not work in IE9, IE8, IE7 and IE6. What could be causing the problem?

Here's my Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/572zA/

Here's my code:

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#question > li > a').click(function () {

if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $('#question>li>ul').slideUp();
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    $('#question>li>a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
} else {
    $('#question>li>ul').slideUp();
    $('#question>li>a').removeClass('active');
}
});
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="question"> 
<li><a href="#!">Question 1</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#!">Answer to question 1 goes here.</a></li>
</ul> 
</li>

<li><a href="#!">Question 2</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#!">Answer to question 2 goes here.</a></li>
</ul> 
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason not to use jQueryUI's accordion widget? Your code is reduced to:

```
$( "#question" ).accordion();
```

<kbd>[Revised jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/572zA/1/)</kbd>

By the way, a big factor in using jQueryUI's accordion widget is that it is certified cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Brilliant - never used JQueryUI's before - will come in handy. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Still struggling to get this to work in IE though! :(

Comment: Got it working in the end, set up a test file and worked back from there, I had a JS conflict that was causing the issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know how you solved it -- good trouble-shooting methodology.